# mongodb error: how do I make sure that your journal directory is mounted

Tags: mongodb

I typed `mongod` on in my mac terminal and got the following error:

```
2015-04-27T22:11:46.471-0400 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean  shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
2015-04-27T22:11:46.479-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ************** 
old lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock.  probably means unclean shutdown,
but there are no journal files to recover.
this is likely human error or filesystem corruption.
please make sure that your journal directory is mounted.
found 4 dbs.
see: http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair for more information
```

How do I make sure my journal directory is mounted?  Will that solve the problem?

Comment: Is it a replica set? Is journaling enabled?

Comment: Off-topic. This definetly is a question to be asked on http://dba.stackexchange.com Hint: you should [read a bit about UNIX like filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system#Unix_and_Unix-like_operating_systems)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have an unclean shutdown. You should start mongod with `--repair` option.

```
mongod --repair
```

Note that after repair you will need to restart mongod

Comment: Solution for docker: `docker-compose run mongo mongod --repair`, where `mongo` is your DB service name, not a container name.

Answer (score 5):

1.**delete  mongo.lock**

2.**Mongod --dbpath path --repair**

3.**mongod --dbpath path**

Run command with Admin accesss.I had sloved in Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

Journal is stored in the path specified in `--dbpath` option. In your case `/data/db/`.

To check if this directory is a mountpoint, use `mountpoint /data/db/`. But I don't think it is the cause.

`/data/db/mongod.lock` exist when mongod starts, and destroyed when mongod shutdown. It's existence means improper shutdown, for whatever reason.

You should remove `mongod.lock`, then issue a `mongod --repair`.

Comment: @Michael The `mongod.lock` prevent two `mongod` instance sharing the same directory. `If the mongod.lock file in the data directory specified by dbPath, /data/db by default, is not a zero-byte file, then mongod will refuse to start` -[http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/). You have to remove it before doing anything else.

Comment: I deleted the file and restarted the mongod again and it worked

Comment: Removing `/data/db/mongod.lock` file fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

For 32Bit you need to use this

```
    mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath [your-path] --repair
```

Answer (score 0):

I received the message "Detected unclean  shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty." and a google search brought me to this question - however my problem was different.

I was on a **mac** and I ran 
`$ mongod` when I should have run ***`$ sudo mongod`***