# Installed docker and ran a container with mongodb, now brew's mongodb isn't working

Tags: mongodb, macos, docker, homebrew

I recently installed docker and ran a container with mongodb, now my local brew's mongodb isn't working.

I am using a mac and originally installed mongodb using homebrew. `brew services list` now shows the mongodb service as 'running' but in yellow (apparently this means unknown), and I cannot connect using mongochef. This began happening after only once stopping the service `brew service stop mongodb`, as it was preventing me from using docker with this project: https://meanjs.org/. I stopped the service because there was a conflict for the mongodb port. Now even after destroying all the docker containers, I can't get mongodb working on my machine. I have tried reinstalling mongodb using brew, and stopping and starting the service.

I have also tried deleting the file in /tmp as here:
[MongoDB Failing to Start - ***aborting after fassert() failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555603/mongodb-failing-to-start-aborting-after-fassert-failure)

Any suggestions about where to look and what to do?

Comment: Did you check whether any process is listening on the MongoDB port?

Comment: lsof -i :27017 is showing nothing

Comment: That means MongoDB is not running. You might get some information from the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

So this turned out to be one of those really annoying problems that comes up when you have a lot of other stuff to do. I am still not completely sure if it was one issue or multiple issues. If I was to try and fix it again though, this is the order I would go in:

I removed mongo completely and reinstalled (this finally fixed the mongodb service's status from being shown in yellow instead of in green), as here: https://gist.github.com/katychuang/10439243:

```
# checks to see if running 
launchctl list | grep mongo

launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
launchctl remove homebrew.mxcl.mongodb

pkill -f mongod

rm -f ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist

brew uninstall mongodb

# double check existence
ls -al /usr/local/bin/mong*
ls -al ~/Library/LaunchAgents

# this was mentioned in the comments
rm -R /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

However, I think my data was corrupted too. Unfortunately `mongod --repair` ([mongodb error: how do I make sure that your journal directory is mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909180/mongodb-error-how-do-i-make-sure-that-your-journal-directory-is-mounted/29909264)) was saying it couldn't repair the data without running with `--journaled` but that didn't work either. So I deleted my databases in `/data/db` I didn't need them anyway because I have backups and just restored them easily.

Hope that can help anyone having similar issues.

### Sidenote:

The `mongod` command on the command line gave some helpful output in tracking this down. 
Also `vim ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist` allowed me to see which command was being run:

```
<string>/usr/local/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod</string>
<string>--config</string>
<string>/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf</string>
```

This showed me that /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf was being used, and realising that whilst running `/usr/local/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod` was working, running:
`/usr/local/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` was not working, helped me narrow the problem down